# OneToMany and ManyToOne mapping in spring boot

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, mapping

I need to create a group with multiple users (which are taken from user table) and single employee for every group in spring boot using rest api.

It means I want to perform OneToMany mapping between group to users and ManyToOne mapping between group and employee.

In fact 1 employee can handle more than one group, and all these data I want in a single table.

Comment: `all these data i want in a single table`: Why do you want it? How about [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: i am making a micro finance web app where admin provide loan in a group and group have multiple users with single employee. and i need to say everyone's emi and amount in a table so i thought i need to store these data in a single table.